# Kusto (with Azure Application Insights): How can I query results based on values in a result set from an initial search query?

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I have a situation where one entity can have multiple ids associated with it, say ID1 and ID2, and I log to app insights and sometimes the records have a customDimensions.ID1 value, sometimes they have a customDimensions.ID2 value, and sometimes they have both values.

So when I want to want to determine what happened to entity ID1=123, I run an initial query to determine what the other ID / ID2 value is, and then I run a query to get records that contain either the ID1 or ID2.

Given ID1="123" I start with something like:

```
    traces 
    | where tostring(customDimensions.ID1) == "123"
    | project
      ID1 = tostring(customDimensions.ID1)
      , ID2 = tostring(customDimensions.ID2)
      , message
```

And results look something like:

```
|ID1|ID2|messsage|
|---|---|--------|
|123||this record doesn't have a second id value|
|123|456|this log record has the other id value that I want to use|
|123||another message|
```

In those results, I get this ID2 value of "456", and I use that in another query:

```
    traces 
    | where tostring(customDimensions.ID1) == "123" or tostring(customDimensions.ID2) == "456" or 
    | project
    ID1 = tostring(customDimensions.ID1)
    , ID2 = tostring(customDimensions.ID2)
    , message
```

And I get more records:

```
|ID1|ID2|messsage|
|---|---|--------|
|123||this log record doesn't have the second id|
|123|456|this log record has other id value that I want to use|
|123||another message|
||456|this record doesn't have ID1, but it has ID2|
||456|again, only has second ID|
```

I'm hoping there is a clever way I can do this in one step / with one query.

It doesn't have to be perfect either and I can make some assumptions like ID1 will only be associated to one other ID2 value (not counting null / empty string)

Without joins, using my imaginary GET-FIRST-VALUE-OF-RESULT() method, I think the solution could look something like:

```
    let myID1 = "123";
    let myID2 = GET-FIRST-VALUE-OF-FIRST-COL-OF-RESULT-SET(
      traces 
      | where * has myID1 
      | where tostring(customDimensions.ID2) != ""
      | project tostring(customDimensions.ID2)
    );
    traces
    | where * has myID1 or * has myID2
```

With joins... I don't know. I'm trying to work through it using a query that gets distinct ID1,ID2 values where either contains my search string, and then I have two subqueries that join traces to that first result set on ID1 and then on ID2, where the right side is not null, and then I union the results.

But this feels super awkward / smells bad. I imagine there is a simpler way to do this. Just to try to sum it up - I want to query for records that contain a search string, then pluck out a set of distinct values from a set of `customDimensions` properties, and then use those values to query records that contain any of the retrieved values from my initial query / queries.

Apologies, I will update with some sample data and the start of a query when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
let myID1 = "123";
let myID2 = toscalar(
traces 
| where tostring(customDimensions.ID1) == myID1
| project ID2 = tostring(customDimensions.ID2)
| where ID2 != ""
| take 1);
traces
| project
    ID1 = tostring(customDimensions.ID1),
    ID2 = tostring(customDimensions.ID2),
    message
| where * has myID1 or ID2 in (myID2)
```

Works perfectly fine using in: `ID2 in (myID2)` but doesn't work with the search expression cause KQL expects a constant string. So `* has myID2` fails with *'The pattern for the search expression must be a constant string'*